# WPF Animation not working correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following storyboard for my Image control, however, when running this code, the last image does not get displayed:

```
<Image Height="15" Width="137" RenderTransformOrigin="0.415,4.583" Canvas.Left="104" Canvas.Top="13">

    <Image.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Reconnect">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>                  
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="reconnectStoryBoardImageChange" >
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/State/Reconnect.png" />
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/State/Reconnect_2.png" />
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/State/Reconnect_3.png" />
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/State/Reconnect_4.png" />
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>                       
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="reconnectStoryBoardImageChange"/>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

What this XAML does it to display different images at different times, but never displays reconnect_4 , it goes till _3 then back to the first image.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the explanation why it is not working the way you expect it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/key-frame-animations-overview#more-about-duration-and-key-times).

> If the animation's Duration is Automatic or its Duration is equal to
>   the time of the last key frame, the animation ends. Otherwise, if the
>   animation's Duration is greater than the key time of the last key
>   frame, the animation holds the key frame value until it reaches the
>   end of its Duration.

So you should specify the `Duration` of the `Storyboard`. I'd do it like this:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Reconnect">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="reconnectStoryBoardImageChange" >
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:04" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/State/Reconnect.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/State/Reconnect_2.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/State/Reconnect_3.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/State/Reconnect_4.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="reconnectStoryBoardImageChange"/>
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

I specified 4 seconds as the `Duration`. The first image is shown from 00:00:00 to 00:00:01. The second image is shown from 00:00:01 to 00:00:02. The third image is shown from 00:00:02 to 00:00:03. Fourth image is shown from 00:00:03 to 00:00:04. Then it restarts.

In your case the last key frame lasts 0 seconds, because your storyboard ends too early.